# Adding shine animation not working in special cases

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this function to shine any text element which is passed to it.

The first example here works fine (the second example doesn't work, I provide this in case this can help us find out the issue):

```js
function Shine(textElement) {
    textElement.classList.remove("shine");
    setTimeout(() => textElement.classList.add("shine"), 20);
    textElement.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
    function shineEnd(e) {
       if (e.animationName === 'shine') {
           //textElement.classList.remove("shine");
           textElement.removeEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
       } 
    } 
}


setTimeout(() => {
    const prepareCaption = document.querySelector(".prepareCaption");
    Shine(prepareCaption);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.prepare-container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 2.5%;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 55vh;
  padding-top: 10px;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prepareCaption {
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #100021) drop-shadow(1px .05em 1px #0d021a);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f8f7fa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0vh;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}



.shine {
  background-color: currentColor;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-42deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: -100%, 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: shine 4s ease-out 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes shine {
  from { background-position: -100%, 0%; }
  to { background-position: 200%, 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="prepare-container">
        <p class="prepareCaption" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 64); font-family: &quot;Open Sans Semibold&quot;; font-size: 28px;">This is shining</p>
    </div>
```

I expect this function work in any satiation but unfortunately we have this second example in which the function acts wired and doesn't work as expected, here it is:

**Note: the shine function is identical in both cases. the only difference is the element I pass to the function.**

Here we want to shine the `expandCaptionSpan` id:

```js
function Shine(textElement) {
    textElement.classList.remove("shine");
    setTimeout(() => textElement.classList.add("shine"), 20);
    textElement.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
    function shineEnd(e) {
       if (e.animationName === 'shine') {
           //textElement.classList.remove("shine");
           textElement.removeEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
       } 
    } 
}


setTimeout(() => {
    const expandCaption = document.querySelector("#expandCaptionSpan");
    Shine(expandCaption);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.expandCaption {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #ff0000; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1; 
  top: 0vh;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.arrow {
  color: #ff9900;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.arrow-samll {
    color: #ff4646;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.left-arrow {
  padding-right: 7vw;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.right-arrow {
  padding-left: 7vw;
}



.shine {
  background-color: currentColor;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-42deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: -100%, 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: shine 4s ease-out 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes shine {
  from { background-position: -100%, 0%; }
  to { background-position: 200%, 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="expand-caption-container">
        <p class="expandCaption"><span class="left-arrow arrow-samll">‹</span>
    <span id="expandCaptionSpan">Permafrost</span><span class="right-arrow arrow-samll">›</span></p>
    </div>
```

How can I fix the second example? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your JS is the same but CSS not. I've found that `text-shadow` is causing the issue. Just replace it with `filter` as it's done in your first example and it works. It seems that the issue is caused by render system.

```js
function Shine(textElement) {
    textElement.classList.remove("shine");
    setTimeout(() => textElement.classList.add("shine"), 20);
    textElement.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
    function shineEnd(e) {
       if (e.animationName === 'shine') {
           //textElement.classList.remove("shine");
           textElement.removeEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", shineEnd);
       } 
    } 
}


setTimeout(() => {
    const expandCaption = document.querySelector("#expandCaptionSpan");
    Shine(expandCaption);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.expandCaption {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold", sans-serif;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);*/
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #ff0000; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1; 
  top: 0vh;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.arrow {
  color: #ff9900;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.arrow-samll {
    color: #ff4646;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.left-arrow {
  padding-right: 7vw;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.right-arrow {
  padding-left: 7vw;
}

.shine {
  background-color: currentColor;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-42deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: -100%, 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: shine 4s ease-out 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes shine {
  from { background-position: -100%, 0%; }
  to { background-position: 200%, 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="expand-caption-container">
        <p class="expandCaption"><span class="left-arrow arrow-samll">‹</span>
    <span id="expandCaptionSpan">Permafrost</span><span class="right-arrow arrow-samll">›</span></p>
    </div>
```